# Test in R for checking if the trend is stochastic or deterministic

Tags: r, testing, time-series, data-modeling

I'm working at time series model and I have problem to understand which times series is stationary with **deterministic** trend and which with **stochastic** trend. I used `adf.test`, `kpss.test`, `Box.test`, `PP.test` but they test only stationarity, not deterministic/stochastic things. I'm looking for test/function  in R that gives answer if the trend is stochastic or deterministic :)

I was thinking about `kpss.test`, but I don't know how to interpret the results.

> **Description** Computes the Kwiatkowski-Phillips-Schmidt-Shin (KPSS) test for the null hypothesis that x is level or trend stationary.
>
> **Usage**
>
> ```
> kpss.test(x, null = c("Level", "Trend"), lshort = TRUE)
> ```
>
> **Arguments**
>
> x a numeric vector or univariate time series.
>
> null indicates the null hypothesis and must be one of "Level" (default) or "Trend".
> You can specify just the initial letter.
>
> lshort a logical indicating whether the short or long version of the truncation lag parameter
> is used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`tseries::kpss` test calculates the kpss test statistic ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13213/how-to-interpret-kpss-results)'s one discussion on how to interpret it from Cross-Validated).

In short, if your test statistic is larger than the critical value corresponding to level a, you would reject your null hypothesis with confidence a. One slightly confusing thing about the kpss implementation in tseries is that the exact p-value for the test does not have a closed form solution. The function just compares your critical value to some preset risk levels.

So for instance,

```
x <- rnorm(1000)  # is level stationary
kpss.test(x)
```

returns

```
KPSS Test for Level Stationarity
KPSS Level = 0.084751, Truncation lag parameter = 7, p-value = 0.1
Warning message: 
In kpss.test(x) : p-value greater than printed p-value
```

The way to read this is that

1. your null hypothesis is level stationarity,
2. your test statistic has value of 0.084751, and
3. the p-value associated with the test stat is larger than 0.1.

In other words, your null hypothesis is not rejected.

If you play around with the examples provided [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tseries/versions/0.10-42/topics/kpss.test) and pay attention to the warning messages returned, you should be able to figure this out.

Kpss tests are known to be underpowered, so if kpss test suggests that your time series has an unit root ("stochastic trend"), it also makes sense to do other tests (such as adf) to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Here is Level stationarity - this means stationarity with stochastic trend, right? But, if I use "Trend stationarity" in KPSS there wil be null stationarity: trend stationarity (so with deterministic trend?)

Comment: 1) Level stationarity = mean stays the same over time = no unit root, no deterministic trend. 2) Trend stationarity = mean changes deterministically = deterministic time trend, no unit root.

Comment: thanks! Should i use kpss test for first diff of time series or time series without modification?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what you are doing exactly. But in general you would probably want to use KPSS to find out which transformations you need to do to get your time series stationary. If for example KPSS would indicate that your time series has a unit root, you would presumably want to first difference to make it stationary.